# how to read messages from pubsub with starting date in Apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a simple job reading historical data from pubsub bounded with dates for example I want to read messages starting from date 2020-04-10 to 2020-04-20 then save messages in google bucket every day in single file

Comment: What's your use case? Beam + PubSub are designed for realtime processing. Not processing in the past

Comment: I am building a data lake for messaging system that save raw messages that are sent in pubsub in google bucket

Comment: How many message do you have (or will you have) per day? What's the expected size of the file per day? Why it's a constrain to have 1 file per day?

Comment: Can you share the code you manage to achieve from now ? If you haven't started yet, maybe this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-dataflow#stream_messages_from_to) will help. Also,  where is the input data coming from to PubSub, can you describe more your logic/process?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a messaging system backed by pubsub and you are trying to build a data lake with historical messaging data from pubsub, you can use [replaying messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview) to either seek to a [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#seek_to_a_time) or a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#seek_to_a_snapshot) to achieve what you want to do.